# language ML function val a’ * a’ * int -> bool

Tags: function, types, sml, ml

In ML language

Suppose `f(x,y,z)` is a function. Give an example of a definition of f that would cause the argument of f to have the type: `a’ * a’ * int`.

sample code

```
fun f1 (x,y,z) =  z<5 ;

val f1 = fn : 'a * 'b * int -> bool
```

how I change this val to `a’ * a’ * int -> bool` ??

Comment: Are you posting all of your homework questions on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type:

```
a’ * a’ * int -> bool
```

means that the function takes three arguments the first is of 'a type, the second also of 'a type and third of type int.

Your definition:

```
fun f1 (x,y,z) =  z<5 ;
```

is in the right way since it takes a tuple, now in order to restrict the type of x,y to be equal you could write:

```
fun f1 (x :'a ,y :'a ,z) =  z<5 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid explicit type annotations, the simplest way to make `x` and `y` the same type is to return both of them from the function but under different circumstances.
Real-world example:

```
- fun f (x,y,z) = if z < 0 then x else y;
val f = fn : 'a * 'a * int -> 'a
```

(Since the `bool` result type isn't mentioned in the problem description, I'm assuming it's just a consequence of your returning `z < 5` and not part of the original problem.)